# i want to auto-update a column when only one column is update

Tags: mysql

i'm normally using the statement **TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT** on the default value for auto timestamp, and it works

But now i'm trying to do this but only if a column is this possible?

or the only way i could do this is using code?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "only if it is a collumn".
Can you write an example

Comment: i have a 4 column in the table (the 4th is the timestamp) i just want update the 4th if the 3rd change values, if the 1st and 2nd changed the value from the 4th still the same

Comment: You can't..you could implement this using a trigger.